# Will making a controller method async improve its performance? What is the benefit?

Tags: c#, rest, asynchronous, api-design

***Disclaimer:*** I've considered thoroughly whether this question is opinion-based, because I understand the importance of following the site's rules. My conclusion is that it's sufficiently specific to be answered here. My deepest apologies if I'll stand corrected.

I chose to write my controller without *async* and *Task*. The way I figured, there was nothing to gain in asynchronizing the operation because of two reasons.

1. The whole view model is served at once and there's no meaningful information to present until the whole content is ready to be rendered (i.e. no list being gradually transferred).
2. The operations in the service need to do some heavy data massage and are based on logic that assumes knowledge of all retrieved elements and also stores certain info prior to exposing it (i.e. no *SaveChangesAsync()* or such is possible and using *AsNoTracking()* is present).

The class describing the view model looks roughly like so.

```
public class TheViewModel
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public byte[] Pieces { get; set; }
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<int, Info> { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public Guid ParentLeftId { get; set; }
  public Guid ParentRightId { get; set; }
  public Guid ParentRandId { get; set; }
  public int[] Data { get; set; }
  public List<DateTime> { get; set; }
}
```

A colleague of mine batted the eye reacting to my choice and argued that:

a. it's not the recommended way,
b. the operation will be performed less efficiently, 
c. it's against best practice.

We googled and read quite some blogs. The general impression tells that the argument is valid. However, I question its relevance in our case. Prestanda is not a democratic issue and can't be opinion-based.

When I tried to look up actual references (MSDN, SO etc.) where it's stated **how exactly** the performance would be affected, I got very little. I haven't found much info on how to reliably test it, neither.

Comment: From the list of your colleague: a) and c) are pretty the same, b) is not totally correct as asynchronicity is about of better throughput utilization thus about efficiency of multiple operations not a single one. As for your question it's not clear what stands behind the "doing some heavy data massage". As a general rule the asynchronicity is beneficial when your flow ends with some I/O because it allows to reduce contention caused by synchronously waiting of an I/O operation completion.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov Let me explain the *heavy data massage*. What I meant was that the logic that transforms the data from DB is being iterated over multiple times, enhancing it and fetching additional data pieces from other databases (an operation the parameters of which aren't available until after the full iteration passing). Basically, what I meant was that I have no option to use *IEnumerable* or *DbSet* at that stage and that I have to realize the data before proceeding. Hence, I sense that there't no point making it more complicated that necessary by adding asynchronicity. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try explaining this in a different way.

Async/await generally helps with IO operations. Those include (but are not limited to): accessing files, accessing a DB, making a call to a webservice, doing something with network sockets, or even accessing some special hardware like a scanner. Basically there are points in time when your code needs to *wait* for the result of some external operation - a file read operation, an SQL query, a HTTP request, whatever.

And this is what async/await helps with. Without it, your thread would be stuck waiting for the results, which usually takes a loooong time. But with it, your thread can switch to doing something else while it's waiting. Thus, your CPU can be used more efficiently.

Note - this isn't multithreading. There is no additional thread that "actually does the work". Instead, deep down underneath all the layers of abstraction, the computer is waiting for some piece of hardware to report back - a hard drive, a network adapter, whatever. (Well, yes, you *can* also wait for another thread to finish doing whatever it's doing, but that's a rather uncommon scenario)

In your scenario, using async/await you could serve two incoming REST requests with a single thread. You'd start on the first one, then it would get to a point where it needs to wait (say, because it was executing an SQL query), and ASP.NET would switch over to doing the second one. Then when the second one gets to wait (or maybe completes), ASP.NET would check back if the SQL results are in and it can continue with the first one. Your thread will never be processing more than one request at the same time, but it will switch back and forth among them - whenever one gets to wait, it'll continue another. Thus you get efficiency.

Mind you, if your requests spend more time calculating something on the CPU than they spend waiting for some external IO, your gains from async/await will be smaller. And if you do **no** IO at all (like your results are dependent only on the request contents), then you indeed don't need any async/await because there's nothing to await.

Even if you do find use for async/await, it won't help any single request process faster - it'll just allow you to process more requests at the same time.

Comment: This is an awesomely great answer. It really lets me evaluate the state of my code. having said that, I was under the impression that a Core (.NET Core) application had the capacity of automagically starting a new thread handled in another core (CPU core that is) when a new request arrived, hence not needing that first, original thread to being with. (Of course, when a bunch of calls come in, the cores will run out eventually but that's besides the point of my consideration on threads being readily available.)

Comment: @KonradViltersten - Yes, it does get a new thread, but only up to a point (you can configure that). If you get a lot of requests, you'll soon run out of threads and everything will get stalled. Async/await helps you get further than that by using each thread to serve multiple requests at the same time. Of course if you know that you will only ever have very few requests to deal with, that's then another case where async/await will bring little benefit. Then again, using them is easy, so why not do it anyway?

Comment: Ah, glad to hear that. Given the intensity of our specific requests, I seem to have made the right call, pragmatically speaking. As for you question - the reason to skip them was a mix of laziness, confusion-of-the-moment and general wtf'ness while coding. I definitely intend to async up the code in the future. The consideration of my is whether I should do it now-now or during the summer when we'll be working on removal of tech debt.

Answer (score 3):

> The whole view model is served at once and there's no meaningful information to present until the whole content is ready to be rendered

This isn't actually the issue.

Somewhere you're likely getting the information from a database (you mentioned saving changes.) If you you interact with the database asynchronously (for example `ExecuteDataReaderAsync`) then awaiting it means that while the query is executing the thread that executed the query can do other things. When the query has finished executing then that thread (or another one, it doesn't matter) will finish.

Allowing a thread to do something else while the query instead of doing nothing but wait increases the performance of the application.

Here's where I think the confusion comes in: How does `async/await` make your controller method execute faster? *It doesn't*. Not at all. In fact, having a threads switch between tasks like this might make it a tiny, tiny bit slower. (This is generally so trivial that you shouldn't worry about it.)

But overall the performance of your application can be faster because however many threads are available - *even if it's just one* - there's a chance that they can be doing something instead of waiting.

The individual things you're doing (like executing a controller method) aren't faster, but you're giving your application a chance to do more with each thread it has. However long something takes it's likely to start sooner because it's not waiting for a thread, which means it finishes *sooner*, not faster.

Even if your application received one request at a time and processed it using just one thread, here's a scenario: What if you make two database or API requests where neither depends on the results of the other? If you process them synchronously you would wait for one to finish, start the next, and wait for the next to finish. If you process them asynchronously, you start the one, and while you're waiting you can start the next one. Neither individual task happens faster. The difference is that the second task starts sooner - while there's nothing to do with the first one but wait.

So while we talk about "threads," it's not really about multiple threads. It's about how each individual thread is used.

Comment: Good answer. In my particular case, the threads can't be executed simultaneously because one depends on the outcome of the other. However, you raised the point that there might be multiple calls, so I see the point. Do you have a suggestion how one might go about measuring the impact? (I can only thing of making a bunch of calls and measuring by hand...)

Comment: The async still helps because while the steps to handle a single request might need to execute sequentially, async frees up the thread to do something else - like handle part of an entirely different request - while it would otherwise just be waiting for a database query to execute. You could test by simulating a database call with a thread.sleep (synchronous) vs. Task.delay (asynchronous.) Maybe I'll work something up.